# builtins.ValueError: generator already executing

Tags: python

```
f = open("test.txt", "r") 
try:
    open_file = f.read() 
finally:
    f.close()

satisfied = 0 
not_satisfied = 0 
distinct = ()
distinct = (variable for variable in open_file if not variable in distinct)
length = len(list(distinct))
for i in 2**length: #len(distinct_set) is the equivalent of 2**n
    binary = bin(i)
    binary_length = len(distinct)
    digits = f"binary:binary_length"
    true_false = ()
    for j in len(distinct): #See slide 24
        true_false.append(digits // 10**j % 10) 
        environments = zip(distinct,true_false)
        if eval(open_file,environments) == True:
            satisfied += 1
        else: 
            not_satisfied += 1            
print('Satisfied: ', satisfied, '; Not Satisfied: ', not_satisfied)
```

The 2 lines:

```
distinct = (variable for variable in open_file if not variable in distinct)
length = len(list(distinct))
```

are giving me a "builtins.ValueError: generator already executing" Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also if there is a more pythonic way to write my code in general that would be super helpful
New to python and would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: As a note, `distinct = (variable for variable in open_file if not variable in distinct)` won't do what you want anyway as the assignment to `distinct` is made *after* it iterates through checking if each value is in `distinct`. You probably want a set and also to remove the newline characters, e.g. `distinct = set(x.rstrip() for x in open_file.readlines())` or, the slightly shorter version, `distinct = {x.rstrip() for x in open_file.readlines()}`.

Comment: @Kemp: No, it's a generator expression, so the assignment happens first. Then the `list` call starts the actual execution, and the genexp tries to perform an `in` test on itself, triggering the exception.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, I'm not that familiar with generator expressions. My solution still works though, even if my diagnosis wasn't right :)

Comment: @Kemp: I don't think I can use readlines() on a string - I am getting an "builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines' exception

Comment: My bad, when I wrote that I thought `open_file` was the file, not the content from the file. Drop the `readlines()`. Should have made this an answer and then I could edit away my embarrassing oversights :D

Comment: @Kemp - Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I will start with an explanation. See a resolution in a section below.

## Explanation

This happens because your `distinct` generator refers to itself inside of its body: `if not variable in distinct`.

`in` operator, when called on a generator, results in iterating over all the elements of the generator. Roughly similar to this:

```py
for item in generator:  # iteration happens here
    if variable == item:  # variable in distinct
        break
```

In other words, this is literally a recursive generator which is "iterated while being iterated".

When you call `list(distinct)`, it executes the generator, that's is why this is the line where an error occurs. The previous line (`distinct = (…)`) is just an assignment, no actual execution happens there.

In fact, this is a very good (and real life!) example of a self-referencing generator. To be honest, I have never expected such a case happen outside of synthetic code snippets, so thank you for sharing

For a detailed explanation of this, let me refer to [my other answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73790573/11222662) related to "generator already executing"/"asynchronous generator is already running" issue (see "Explanation" and "Sync generators example" sections).

## Resolution

To resolve your particular use case, you should use a Python's builtin `set` type: it is designed specifically to store unique items and *efficiently* check their presence within the container:

```py
distinct = set(open_file)
```

`set` will iterate the `open_file` lines and preserve only unique ones. Starting from Python 3.6, `set` preserves insertion order. Same as `dict`, since they rely on the same implementation of a hash table. Though, this feature is documented only starting from Python 3.7+, in Python 3.6 this was experimental yet supported.

A verbose code sample, if you need `distinct` to be a generator:

```py
def uniq(input_items):
    uniq_values = set()
    for variable in input_items:
        if variable not in uniq_values:
            yield variable
            uniq_values.add(variable)
distinct = uniq(open_file)  # generator with unique items
```