# Python: asynchronous generator is already running

Tags: python, python-asyncio

As in the following example, I encountered an unusual error when using async Generator.

```py
async def demo():
    async def get_data():
        for i in range(5):  # loop: for or while
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # some IO code

            yield i

    datas = get_data()

    await asyncio.gather(
        anext(datas),
        anext(datas),
        anext(datas),
        anext(datas),
        anext(datas),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.run(demo())
```

Console output:

```
2022-05-11 23:55:24,530 DEBUG asyncio 29180 30600 Using proactor: IocpProactor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\workspace\develop\python\crawlerstack-proxypool\demo.py", line 77, in <module>
    asyncio.run(demo())
  File "D:\devtools\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "D:\devtools\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "E:\workspace\develop\python\crawlerstack-proxypool\demo.py", line 66, in demo
    await asyncio.gather(
RuntimeError: anext(): asynchronous generator is already running
```

Situation description: I have a loop logic that fetches a batch of data from Redis at a time, and I want to use yield to return the result. But this error occurs when I create a concurrent task.

Is there a good solution to this situation? I don't mean to change the way I'm using it now, but to see if I can tell if it's running or something like a lock and wait for it to run and then execute anext.

Maybe my logic is not reasonable now, but I also want to understand some critical language, let me realize the seriousness of this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need an async generator for this at all. If you have `get_data` perform whatever operation `asyncio.sleep` is simulating and then return its result, you can just gather `get_data` five (or however many the real number is) times.

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR: the right way

Async generators suit badly for a parallel consumption. See my explanations below. As a proper workaround, use `asyncio.Queue` for the communication between producers and consumers:

```py
queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def producer():
    for item in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())  # imitate async fetching
        print('item fetched:', item)
        await queue.put(item)

async def consumer():
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())  # imitate async processing
        print('item processed:', item)

await asyncio.gather(producer(), consumer(), consumer())
```

The above code snippet works well for an *infinite* stream of items: for example, a web server, which runs forever serving requests from clients. But what if we need to process a finite number of items? **How should `consumer`s know when to stop?**

This deserves another question on Stack Overflow to cover all alternatives, but the simplest option is a `sentinel` approach, described below.

### Sentinel: finite data streams approach

Introduce a `sentinel = object()`. When all items from an external data source are fetched and put to the queue, `producer` must push as many `sentinel`s to the queue as many `consumer`s you have. Once a `consumer` fetches the `sentinel`, it knows it should stop: `if item is sentinel: break` from loop.

```py
sentinel = object()
consumers_count = 2

async def producer():
    ...  # the same code as above
    if new_item is None:  # if no new data
        for _ in range(consumers_count):
            await queue.put(sentinel)

async def consumer():
    while True:
        ...  # the same code as above
        if item is sentinel:
            break

await asyncio.gather(
    producer(),
    *(consumer() for _ in range(consumers_count)),
)
```

## TL;DR [2]: a dirty workaround

Since you require to not change your async generator approach, here is an asyncgen-based alternative. To resolve this issue (in a simple-yet-dirty way), you may wrap the source async generator with a lock:

```py
async def with_lock(agen, lock: asyncio.Lock):
    while True:
        async with lock:  # only one consumer is allowed to read
            try:
                item = await anext(agen)
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                break
        # exiting lock section => let others consume
        yield item  # consumer processes an item asyncly

lock = asyncio.Lock()  # a common lock for all consumers
await asyncio.gather(
    # every consumer must have its own "wrapped" generator
    anext(with_lock(datas, lock)),
    anext(with_lock(datas, lock)),
    ...
)
```

This will ensure *only one* consumer awaits for an item from the generator *at a time*. While this consumer awaits, other consumers are being executed, so parallelization is not lost.

Important! In the above approach do *not* `yield await anext(agen)` as a single expression under the `lock`: your wrapping generator will suspend (on `yield`) with `lock` *unreleased* and no other consumer will be able to consume another item in parallel. I.e. only wrap `anext` call with a lock, but do not `yield` in the lock section.

A roughly equivalent code with `async for` (looks a little smarter):

```py
async def with_lock(agen, lock: asyncio.Lock):
    await lock.acquire()
    async for item in agen:
        lock.release()
        yield item
        await lock.acquire()
    lock.release()
```

However, this code only handles async generator's `anext` method. Whereas generators API also includes `aclose` and `athrow` methods. See an explanation below.

Though you may add support for those to the `with_lock` function too, I would recommend to either subclass a generator and handle the lock support inside, or better use the `Queue`-based approach from above.

See [`contextlib.aclosing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.aclosing) for some inspiration.

## Explanation

Both sync and async generators have a special attribute: `.gi_running` (for regular generators) and `.ag_running` (for async ones). You may discover them by executing `dir` on a generator:

```py
>>> dir((i for i in range(0))
[..., 'gi_running', ...]
```

They are set to `True` when a generator's `.__next__` or `.__anext__` method is executed (`next(...)` and `anext(...)` are just a syntactic sugar for those).

This prevents re-executing `next(...)` on a generator, when another `next(...)` call on the same generator is already being executed: if the running flag is `True`, an exception is raised (for a sync generator it raises `ValueError: generator already executing`).

So, returning to your example, when you run `await anext(datas)` (via `asyncio.gather`), the following happens:

1. `datas.ag_running` is set to `True`.
2. An execution flow steps into the `datas.__anext__` method.
3. Once an inner `await` statement is reached inside of the `__anext__` method (`await asyncio.sleep(1)` in your case), `asyncio`'s loop switches to another consumer.
4. Now, another consumer tries to call `await anext(datas)` too, but since `datas.ag_running` flag is still set to `True`, this results in a `RuntimeError`.

### Why is this flag needed?

A generator's execution can be suspended and resumed. But only at `yield` statements. Thus, if a generator is paused at an inner `await` statement, it cannot be "resumed", because its state disallows it.

That's why a parallel `next`/`anext` call to a generator raises an exception: it is not ready to be resumed, it *is already running*.

### `athrow` and `aclose`

Generators' API (both sync and async) includes not only `send`/`asend` method for iteration, but also:

- `close`/`aclose` to release generator-allocated resources (e.g. a database connection) on exit or an exception
- and `throw`/`athrow` to inform generator that it has to handle an exception.

`aclose` and `athrow` are async methods too. Which means that if two consumers try to close/throw an underlying generator in parallel, you will encounter the same issue since a generator will be closing (or handling an exception) while closed (thrown an exception) again.

### Sync generators example

Though this is a frequent case for async generators, reproducing it for sync generators is not that naive, since sync `next(...)` calls are rarely interrupted.

One of the ways to interrupt a sync generator is to run a multithreaded code with multiple consumers (run in parallel threads) reading from a single generator. In that case, when the generator's code is interrupted while executing a `next` call, all other consumers' parallel attempts to call `next` will result in an exception.

Another way to achieve this is demonstrated in the [generators-related PEP #255](https://peps.python.org/pep-0255/#specification-yield) via a self-consuming generator:

```py
>>> def g():
...     i = next(me)
...     yield i
... 
>>> me = g()
>>> next(me)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in g
ValueError: generator already executing
```

When outer `next(me)` is called, it sets `me.gi_running` to `True` and then executes the generator function code. A subsequent inner `next(me)` call leads to a `ValueError`.

## Conclusion

Generators (especially async) work the best when consumed by a single reader. Multiple consumers support is hard, since requires patching behaviour of all the generator's methods, and thus discouraged.